# Is there any COMPACT way to check winner in a simple tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am coding a simple tic-tac-toe for a high-school mini project, but I need it to be within a strict data volume (not more than 112 lines). I thought checking for each row, column and cross would be long, so is there any alternative to do so (You should see a [[[HERE]]] comment)? (Btw, I already know it looks awful) Thanks in advance!

```
public class TTTGame {
    //OPTIONS v
    public static final String draw = "DRAW"; // <- Definitions for different states
    public static final String circles = "CIRCLES"; // BOT
    public static final String crosses = "CROSSES"; // PLAYER
    public static final String getCrosses = "X"; //<- Symbols to display
    public static final String getCircles = "O";
    //OPTIONS ^

    //DO NOT MODIFY UNDER THIS LINE (Just kidding, do whatever u want) v

    public static int[][] board = {
            {0,0,0},
            {0,0,0},
            {0,0,0},
    };
    public static final int empty = 0; // Definition of the values
    public static final int cross = 1;
    public static final int circle = 2;
    public static int turns = 0; //Just here to count turns, nothing special

    public static void main(String[]args) { //Main process
        board[1][1] = circle;
        display();
        while (true) {
            PlayerTurn();
            if (checkStop()||checkWinner()!=null) {display();GStop();break;}
            BotTurn();
            if (checkStop()||checkWinner()!=null) {display();GStop();break;}
            display();
            turns += 1;
        }
    }

    private static void GStop() { //Force stop the match function
        System.out.println("Winner : " + checkWinner());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    private static boolean checkStop() { //Check if match is already full / completed (Draw)
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                if (board[x][y]==empty) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    private static String checkWinner() { //Check Winner


        //    [[[ HERE ]]]   ---------------



        return null;
    }
    private static void PlayerTurn() { //Player turn
        int x; Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
                x = c.nextInt();
                x = x-1;
                if ((x>=0)&&(x < 9)) {
                    if (board[x / 3][x % 3] == empty) {
                        board[x / 3][x % 3] = cross;
                        break;
                    } else System.out.println("Already chosen");
            } else System.out.println("Invalid");
        }

    }

    private static void BotTurn() { //Bot turn -> (Modify these to change the AI behaviour, here's a very simple one);
        boolean choose = true;
        for (int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                if (board[y][x] == empty&&choose) {
                        board[y][x] = circle;
                        choose = false;
                }
    }
    private static void display() { //Display the board
        int nn = 1;
        String a = "z";
        for (int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                if (board[y][x] == 0) a = "*";
                if (board[y][x] == 1) a = getCrosses;
                if (board[y][x] == 2) a = getCircles;
                System.out.print(a + "  ");
            }
            System.out.print("      "); //Indications
            for (int xn = 0; xn < 3; xn++) {
                System.out.print(nn);
                nn+=1;
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CNF? DNF? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Comment: You can see how others have approached the problem: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this idea: (neither the only nor the best nor the most performant solution... just an idea)

You can use the sum of each row, diagonal and column to determine if the either player one (all `1`s) or player two (all `2`s) wins. Therefore you only need to set the empty field to be higher than 6.

For example let's say your board looks like this:

```
7 1 1    -> 7+1+1 = 9 // no one wins
2 2 2    -> 2+2+2 = 6 // player two wins, he has 3 * 2 in a row
1 7 2    -> 1+7+2 =10 // no win here
```

if all three numbers where `1`s (`sum == 3`) your player one wins.

It is "cumbersome" to implement, but as I said it is just an idea:

```
// first we check every column
for( int x=0; x<board[y].length; x++){
   int sum = 0;
   for( int y=0; y<board.length; y++){
      sum += board[y][x];
   }
   if(sum == 3 || sum == 6){
      return true;
   }
}

// then every row
for( int y=0; y<board.length; y++){
   int sum = 0;
   for( int x=0; x<board[y].length; x++){
      sum += board[y][x];
   }
   if(sum == 3 || sum == 6){
      return true;
   }
}
// and finally the diagonals (if we ever reach that part)
int sum= board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2];
if(sum == 3 || sum == 6){
   return true;
}
sum= board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0];
if(sum == 3 || sum == 6){
   return true;
}
```

you could also return `1` when the `sum == 3` and the first player wins or `2` when player two wins.

Comment: a few more comments on style to keep your code clean and readable (just some advice): methods and variables (usually) start with smaller case letter (`botTurn` not `BotTurn`), only classes start with capital letters. Why `GStop` - what does it  mean? Give your methods and variables meaningful names (like `display` which is very clear). It is often even useful to call your indices `row` instead of `x` or `col` or `column`.  Always use `{` and `}` for ifs and loops and put every expression in its own line (`{display();GStop();break;}` can quickly become unreadable).